# iPhone: How to download a full website?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, download, web-crawler

what approach do you recommend me for downloading a website (one HTML site with all included images) to the iPhone?

The question is how to crawl all those tiny bits (Javascripts, images, CSS) and save them locally. It's not about the concrete implementation (I know how to use NSURLRequest and stuff. I'm looking for a crawl/spider approach).

Jail breaks won't work, since it is intended for an official (App Store) app.

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Are you trying to do this in *your own app*, or from an existing app?

Comment: Yes, I try to do this in my own app. So I'm looking for a approach, how to code this in Objective-C.

Comment: @Stefan: Are you trying to download a whole website (for example: apple.com with all subfiles and folders, like apple.com/iphone/, apple.com/store and so on), or are you trying to get one web **page**, like  this one?

Comment: Ah, now I see. No, I try to download one web page. However, for this single page I need all the subfiles and subfolders (e.g. /stylesheets/test.css).

Comment: So, you need all files needed to display the page?

Comment: @Emil: Yes, all files, I can get :-)

Comment: [Read updated answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073132/iphone-how-to-download-a-full-website/3073154#3073154)

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, please make sure you honor the robots.txt file of the web site being snarfed.

Answer (score 3):

Downloading? Or getting the HTML-source of the site and displaying it with a `UIWebView`?

If last, you could simply do this:

```
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

// Load UIWebView with data
[webView loadHTMLString:data baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];
```

**EDIT:**
For this approach, you would probably be best off using a regex-library for iPhone to parse through the string and find needed objects.

You could use this: [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/), and do a couple of Regex-expressions to find, for example, `<link rel="%" href="*">` and `src="*"`. But you have to remember to store them and replacing the values of * with the new path.

**Storing files:**

You will get url's back from the regex-methods, and you can write the files from the url's like this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString pathToCurrentSite = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/", fullUrlToPage]];
for (urlString in urlStrings) {
    NSData *stringData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:[pathToCurrentSite stringByAppendingPathComponent:urlString] contents:stringData attributes:nil];
}
NSString *data;
NSData *pageData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:[pathToCurrentSite stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index"] contents:pageData attributes:nil];
[fileManager release];
```

Comment: Not a down voter, but I think he asked for downloading a whole website, not just a single HTML page. You might consider updating your answer to add info about parsing the HTML, pulling the links into a queue and looping it. Any solution that doesn't require a jailbreak is better than mine IMHO.

Comment: Hm, he wrote *one HTML-site*, so I don't think he meant a whole website. That's not what I thought of when reading his question, anyway :)

Comment: And he also didn't say anything about doing it from an existing app, or creating his own. So, since SO is a **coding** -website, I obviously though of a code-solution.

Comment: Emil, I voted your answer up. And I know how to download a single page. But the core of my question is how to crawl and download all the tiny parts of a website in order to save it. Regards, Stefan

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe I'll edit my answer if I find something relevant on this.

Comment: Ok, Regex parsing sounds like a good idea. I will try to find a list of things, I need to parse. Thanks

Comment: You most likely only need to parse the things I wrote here, scr= is used for images and iFrames (about the only things that need to be stored) and stylesheets of course. There may be more, so it's probably a good idea to try to find out more about what you need to parse. You said earlier that you might want to download all subitems of the file, but I don't think that will work, images and stylesheets may be located in folders above the file, or even on other websites. I think this is the approach you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

- Install [wget](http://www.pure-mac.com/iphone/filetransfer.html#wget) on your jail broken iPhone
- Use the [spanning hosts](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Spanning-Hosts) options to download everything from the site.

  `wget -rH -Dserver.com http://www.server.com/`

But why do you want to do this on a mobile device? This is somthing that should be done on a real computer with lots of memory, disk space, bandwidth and multiple CPU cores.

Comment: Sorry, as I want to publish my app on the App Store, I can't use jail breaks. ;-)

Comment: @Stefan You should probably have mentioned that in your post, people got confused :)

Comment: Why I want to do this mobile? To allow users to save a website (to be precise: a web page) locally for viewing it offline. I don't want to crawl the whole website with every subpage. I only want to crawl one page for all subfiles and subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for similar functionality and found this.  Can't claim any credit for it, just wanted to make sure it was mentioned (as a drop-in solution) for people interested in it.

http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol

Answer (score -1):

You can't save websites to your phone, only view them (unless your jailbroken.)

Hope this clears up your confusion,
Lee.

Comment: Wrong, you can save the source-code and later use that in a UIWebView.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the Appstore link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sitesucker/id346896838?mt=8
The app downloads entire websites natively to the phone.