# Writing a script to download everything on a server

Tags: python, bash, http, web-crawler

I want to download all the files that are publicly accessible on this site:

```
https://www.duo.uio.no/
```

This is the site for the university of Oslo, and here we can find every paper/thesis that is publicly available from the archives of the university. I tried a crawler, but the website has set some mechanism for stopping crawlers accessing their documents. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Did not mention this in the original question, but what I want is all the pdf files on the server. I tried SiteSucker, but that seems to just download the site itself.

Comment: What's a "crawler"?  Do you mean `wget` or `curl`?  If not, try those.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3073161/2545927

Comment: If you want to use python, take a look at Selenium. Not so easy to block.

Comment: This is not for python but might be of help http://superuser.com/q/14403

Comment: @elyase thanks, will look into Selenium, I thought that was for Java, but if there is a Python version that's great!

Comment: This university is kind enough to provide these documents for free, but requests that you don't thrash their servers. So **please** show a little respect! Determine what docs you actually want and use wget (or a custom script) to _only_ DL those files, preferably in smallish batches. If you really must get all their PDFs, wget can _easily_ let you do that. See the wget man, [4.2 Types of Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files)

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually, I have an agreement to download all these pdf's, it is a project I'm working on to create a word list, and I have permission to use these files as a corpus. I just need to figure out how to download all the pdf's. I may have a solution now, just spoke with a guy at the IT department, and there is a protocol to get these files, although I haven't figured out how that works.

Comment: Well, I guess that's ok, then. :) If you can't figure out their protocol, the wget man link I posted above should give you enough info to download all the PDFs (& only the PDFs) on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=unix,ascii --domains your-site.com --no-parent http://your-site.com`

try it

Comment: Thanks, will do. I forgot to mention in my question, what I'm really trying to do is get all the pdf files that are on the server. Is there a way to use wget so that it will only return pdf files? Sorry for not having said that in question.

Comment: my script will return the entire site, if you need only pdf files, then you need another way

Comment: @ArashSaidi You can't really get the PDF files without at least getting the pages linking to the PDF files first - that's how any program crawls a web site.

Comment: but you can download the entire site, then from the local copy of site store the pdf files

Comment: @IvanIvanovich Ok, but would there be a way to get the crawler to store pdf files in a specific folder, so that I don't have to search and find the files later (I mean, I could write a script for that later on I guess).

Comment: This just downloaded the index.html file, nothing more.

Comment: easy way to download only pdf files does not exist or I can not think of a way to

Comment: works for me and downloads the whole site

try it: in scripts where `--domains your-site.com` change it to `--domains duo.uio.no` and where `--no-parent http://your-site.com` change to `--no-parent https://www.duo.uio.no/`

Comment: @IvanIvanovich So, when you downloaded, did you get all the pdf's?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not look it.

try run my script as i decribe previously

`--domains duo.uio.no` `--no-parent https://www.duo.uio.no/`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using site sucker ([download](http://www.sitesucker.us)), that allows you to download the contents of a website, ignoring any rules they may have in place.

Comment: If it's only a like you can make it as a comment since it's not answering the question.